# Increase worker amount in cluster does not increase total performance anymore

Tags: node.js, performance, cluster-computing, worker

I'm experimenting Node.js [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#clusterismaster) features along with [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/), here is my little script that for testing:

```js
// server.js
import { createServer } from 'http'

const { pid } = process
const server = createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end(`Hello from ${pid}`)
})

server.listen('8080', () => console.log(`Started at ${pid}`))
```

and I use [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) for load test:

```sh
wrk -c 200 -d 10 -t 4 http://localhost:8080
```

I use PM2 to start `server.js` and wrk to perform load test, adding one instance of the running service for each test. Here are the results:

```
server.js with 1 instance   --> Requests/sec:  46139.15
server.js with 2 instances  --> Requests/sec:  89343.35
server.js with 3 instances  --> Requests/sec:  124294.58
server.js with 4 instances  --> Requests/sec:  137826.08
server.js with 5 instances  --> Requests/sec:  134193.62
server.js with 12 instances --> Requests/sec:  123073.60
```

(All the actions is performed in my local machine, which is a iMac with Intel i9-9900K (16 logic core) @ 3.60GHz CPU)

As you can see, starting from 4 instances, the performance gains is becoming smaller. And starting from experiments with 5 instances, the **performance decreases instead**(I can confirm that the network load is not maxed out at this point, which is just 65MB/s, compared to the network card's capacity with 1GB/s).

Another strange behavior is that as the number of instances increases, the cpu usage also increases when testing, but the performance is as described above.

So my question is: **Why does the performance drop when the instances reach 5? It seems that adding instances does not increase performance any more.**

Comment: Are you running the load tester program on the same host as the server?  If so, you're clouding the test results by putting the client in the same set of CPUs.  Also, testing to localhost isn't going through your network card at all.  You really need to get the load tester off the same host and onto the network to have any meaningful measure of real world performance.

Comment: And, can you show your clustered code?  You're currently only showing code for a single instance.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hi, I'm running all the actions include stress test in my local machine, but when the instances amount is 5, the CPU usage is only about 50%. And I use PM2 to start the cluster: pm2 start server.js -i 5, and scale the server by pm2 scale command.

Comment: So, you're not actually using coding nodejs clustering yourself?  But, relying on PM2 entirely?  I have no idea how efficient that is.

Comment: Well, running the client-side of the stress test on the same host will NEVER allow you to get clear results.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm currently doing, I'll try to stress test the cluster in another machine with Node.js built-in cluster module involved and get back to here.

Comment: Unless there is some other bottleneck that is obscuring or influencing things, once you get the client load off the same host and onto the actual network, we would expect that you should see increasing throughput until you get as many clustered servers as you have actual CPUs.  Probably once you get past 8, the benefits in going all the way to 16 are not much because those additional 8 aren't actual CPUs - they're just slightly more efficient "threads" sharing a CPU.

Comment: But, since your server doesn't really do much that is CPU intensive, you may not be CPU-bound at all (and your low CPU usage implies that too).  You may be network bound or some other bottleneck that occurs long before you get to a CPU limit.  If you add a 100ms spin loop to your request handler to simulate CPU load, you will probably see different results.  Keep in mind that more CPUs only helps when you're CPU-bound.

Comment: @jfriend00 After off the stress test load onto another machine that running in the same local network, I only get req/sec about 10000+, but I notice that the latency is relative high (20 - 25ms), and the CPU usage of the server machine is just 5% per process (this time I started 5 instances). So I guess maybe my network latency is the bottleneck in this case, while something else (that I do not know) becomes the bottleneck when the stress test and the service are on the same machine (far before CPU usage is full, like there are 4 or 5 instances).

Comment: I just had another test that added some CPU-intensive code `let i = 1e8; while (i > 0) { i— }` before `res.send`. And the result is just as you said, the CPU usage of every process in the cluster is about to 100%, and as I increase
the number of instances, the req/sec increases until the number of instances reached 8.

Comment: Cool.  That explains it.  I tried to encapsulate the most relevant comments in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your server doesn't really do much that is CPU intensive, you may not be CPU-bound at all (and your low CPU usage implies that too). You may be network bound or some other bottleneck that occurs long before you get to a CPU limit.  Thus when you add CPUs beyond some level, you don't see benefit.

If you add a 100ms spin loop to your request handler to create actual CPU load, you will probably see very different results and adding more CPUs should show more benefit. Keep in mind that more CPUs only helps when you're actually CPU-bound.

Also, keep in mind that with your processor where you have 8 real cores that are hyperthreaded to appear to have 16 cores, those extra 8 are really just "more efficient" threads.  If you aren't doing a lot of thread context switching, then those extra 8 virtual CPUs may not provide any real benefit.

And, the most accurate testing of your server configuration will be when the client load is on a different host and you are actually using the network to send/receive requests.  localhost requests don't actually go through the network.